# Error buying 2 attributes from the same JPA entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class and I want to compare 2 attributes of it in a jpa query, the problem is that I don't know how to do it since the traditional way gives error:

```
@Query("select s from Stock s Where s.cantidad < s.cantidadMinima");
```

Comment: and the error is?

Comment: How do you "buy" something from an entity?

Comment: I already soliucione, the truth that threw me error and I do not know what the reason was. Restart everything and walked out.